# Cannot open RTMP stream with FFMPEG Java Cannot assign requested address

Tags: java, ffmpeg, rtmp, javacv, bytedeco-javacv

I am trying to open an RTMP stream with `avformat_open_input` and for some reason i keep getting `Cannot assign requested address` error.
My RTMP URL is correct because i can watch the stream using VLC Player and ffmpeg command line:
`ffmpeg -i rtmp://1.1.1.1/app/teststream -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4`

```
int timeout = 2500;
setConnectionTimeout(timeout);

AVDictionary optionsDictionary = new AVDictionary();

String timeoutStr = String.valueOf(this.timeoutMicroSeconds);
av_dict_set(optionsDictionary, "timeout", timeoutStr, 0);

int analyzeDurationUs = 1500 * 1000;
String analyzeDuration = String.valueOf(analyzeDurationUs);
av_dict_set(optionsDictionary, "analyzeduration", analyzeDuration, 0);

int ret;

if ((ret = avformat_open_input(inputFormatContext, streamUrl, null, optionsDictionary)) < 0) {
  // ERROR Cannot assign requested address
}
```

I am using `org.bytedeco:ffmpeg:5.1.2-1.5.8 (ffmpeg-5.1.2-1.5.8.jar)`

Why i can't open it?

Comment: If you pass `null` for options, it returns the same error? I'd suggest trying this code in native C/C++ code for ffmpeg. Although it seems it should have the same behaviour but code sometimes behaves differently when executed on lower-level stages. Also I'd check a basic RTP stream from the official streaming guide for ffmpeg (in C and Java). And regarding formatting, I'd recommend posting the full code. What is `inputFormatContext` for example, and `streamUrl`. Better with import also, really helps to discard secondary stuff.

Comment: you were right passing null fixed the problem

ffmpeg backwards comp is not the best

Comment: ok, glad it worked, easier than I thought :)

Answer (score 0):

just pass null as optionsDictionary if its rtmp. ffmpeg backwards comp is not the best